# Facebook php sdk4 and app

Tags: php, facebook

I'm developing with Laravel a package to post on facebook. My code responsible for obtaining and storing the access token of the page post a link besides test makes this operation correctly with an app that I have created test fb . The problem is to create another app on facebook to put it into production , this second app facebook created it with **the same configuration** that does work but when publishing gives me the following error: (# 200 ) The user hasn 't Authorized the application to perform this action .

This is the code snippet I use for testing .

```
 public function getTest(){

   //$accessToken = new AccessToken($this->getParam('TOKEN'));
        try {

                  $page_post = (new FacebookRequest($this->session, 'POST', '/'.$this->getParam('PAGE_ID').'/feed', array(
                'access_token' => $this->getParam('TOKEN'),

                'link' => 'link',
                'description' => 'Hola mundo desde laravel',
                'picture' => 'link/img.png',
                'message' => 'Messge',
            ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
// return post_id
            print_r( $page_post );
        } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
            var_dump($this->getParam('TOKEN'));
            echo  $e->getMessage();
           // var_dump($e);
            exit;
        }
```

As for the authorization of the application is correctly even when you enter to view user applications see 2 ( The works and which not) , both with the same permissions accepted.

Comment: Which API call are you doing when you get that error? And have the user authorized the app to do that?

Comment: This is the code snippet I use for testing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed , I lacked a permit : ' publish_pages '

```
 $params = array(
                'scope' => 'manage_pages','publish_actions','publish_stream','publish_pages'
            );
```